# SQL Server Merge Statement to return zero if no record for an id

Tags: sql-server, merge

I am using a merge statement to update the number of courses complete in the `ModuleEnrollment` table. This works but however if a course is removed from an Employee, then it still remains at its previous value. Is there a way to include in the merge statment to return 0 for any `EmployeeID` not included in the `CoursesComplete` Table.

```
 MERGE [dbo].[ModuleEnrollment] as ME
 USING  [dbo].[CoursesComplete]AS CC
 ON ME.[EmployeeID] = CC.[EmployeeID] AND ME.[ModuleID] = CC.[ModuleID]
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET ME.[CoursesComplete]=CC.[CoursesComplete]
 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
      INSERT([EmployeeID],[ModuleID],[CoursesComplete]) VALUES(CC. 
[EmployeeID],CC.[ModuleID],CC.[CoursesComplete]);

GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add:

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
    UPDATE SET ME.[CoursesComplete]=0
```

The whole query:

```
;MERGE [dbo].[ModuleEnrollment] as ME
 USING  [dbo].[CoursesComplete]AS CC
 ON ME.[EmployeeID] = CC.[EmployeeID] AND ME.[ModuleID] = CC.[ModuleID]
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET ME.[CoursesComplete]=CC.[CoursesComplete]
 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
      INSERT([EmployeeID],[ModuleID],[CoursesComplete]) VALUES(CC. 
[EmployeeID],CC.[ModuleID],CC.[CoursesComplete])
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
        UPDATE SET ME.[CoursesComplete]=0;
```